# implementing a scatterplot in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to learn how to make a scatterplot with this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118

I want to change the data so it can graph "Enrollment" over "Year" instead of "sepalLength" over "sepalWidth".

When I substitute the given DATA with my own data it graphs correctly, except when I try to substitute the TITLE (i.e., Enrollment for sepalLength) nothing shows up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the method that you use to format your data file there is a possibility that using a tab separated file may not have the tabs in the right place or even that the tabs may not be there.

I suggest that you make a csv file instead (comma separated values) and test that. Just name the file data.csv and change the

`d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {`

piece of code to

`d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {`

You don't need to create the whole file to test the idea, just put a few values in to test and see how it comes out.

It might also be useful for you to post your data file (or a sample that you can test which you know doesn't work).